# Tool for counting total needed lines of code in a Java project (including code in library projects)

Tags: java

I'm looking for a tool that traverses Java source code files starting with some class that I can pick and gives me a total of all lines or code that are needed to successfully compile the project (excluding comments, blank lines, and lines in methods or classes that are never used (directly or indirectly) or that declare variables that are never used). The tool should be able to traverse into libraries as well if I provide the source-code.

Comment: __Never used__ is a tricky concept, `if 0` is easy but `if politician_truthful` you might know is never but would a tool?

Comment: @SteveBarnes It would definitely be a bit much to ask it to try and determine all possible actual code-paths. That would probably be as intractable as the halting problem. I was just looking for something that prunes the code before counting. I.e. doesn't count any classes, fields, or methods that can never be reached, no matter what any of the if-conditions evaluate to (ignoring classes, fields, and methods reached via reflection is fine, of course). Basically exactly what ProGuard does.